# I need to perform a task when the Quartz scheduler is shutting down

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a requirement in which I have to do a certain database relted activity when my Quartz   will be shut down. I mean I have to wipe out a certain data from the database when I shutdown the scheduler. Is there any way I can achieve this?

While googling I came across methods to determine the present state of the scheduler. But, is there a way I can capture this scheduler shutdown event.

Thanks in Advance, 
Ibu

Answer (score 4):

Can you add a [ScheduleListener](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/api/org/quartz/SchedulerListener.html) and watch for calls on [schedulerShutdown()](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/api/org/quartz/SchedulerListener.html#schedulerShutdown%28%29) ?

e.g. Implement an instance of ScheduleListener (which would probably *only* do something for the implementation of schedulerShutdown().

Then add it to your scheduler instance using Scheduler.addSchedulerListener(). That way your instance of SchedulerListener should get a callback when the scheduler shuts down.

This assumes the scheduler shuts down cleanly. You *may* have to add a Runtime [shutdownHook](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) to ask the scheduler to shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brian, a simple example would really help me a lot to understand.

Comment: I've not done this (I confess) but I've enhanced my answer a little. Hopefully that should get you going....

Comment: Hey, gr8.. it worked.. 1 more query if you dont mind ;).. Although I am pretty sure there's no way I can do any activity in case my Scheduler does not shut down cleanly(ex: i closed the command window/ pressed ctrl+c while scheduler is still running), u think there's any such way or turnaround I can handle this?

Comment: Probaly not. But have you implemented a shutdown hook, which should get called in most cases when the JVM gets a shutdown request ?